# Micro ROS build stuck after step one in raspberry Pi 3

Tags: ros2, microcontroller, raspberry-pi, ros-humble

I am running ROS2 Humble on my Raspberry Pi 3 and I also have a Raspberry Pi Pico running micro ROS. I am trying to install the micro ROS agent on my RPi3. The snap version of the micro ROS agent did not work due to no stable release for arm. I tried building the micro ROS agent from:
https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_setup#building-micro-ros-agent

The process is stuck on [1/2 completed] for over 2 hours. Is this normal or is something wrong? How can I fix this or install a pre-built version of micro ROS agent on the RPi3.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the required RAM to build the package. RPi 3 did not have sufficient RAM to build it, and was stuck because of that. The issue is mentioned on the github. https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_setup/issues/601